# ctx.fillRect value change is not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is the JS http://jsfiddle.net/T2zsM/ where i can change the value of ctx.fillRect only on click of increment but it does not work for decrement.

```
var Canvas = document.getElementById("Fruits");
var btnnum = document.getElementById("Number");
var btnDec = document.getElementById("decrease");
var btnInc = document.getElementById("increase");
btnnum.value = 10;
var ctx = Canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, btnnum.value);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
var poleBar = function (tempVal) {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, tempVal);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
}
var inc = function () {
    btnnum.value = parseInt(btnnum.value) + 1;
    poleBar(btnnum.value);
}
var dec = function () {
    btnnum.value = parseInt(btnnum.value) - 1;
    poleBar(btnnum.value);
}
btnInc.addEventListener("click", inc, false);
btnDec.addEventListener("click", dec, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not clearing the canvas so whatever is drawn does not dissapear, you can use `clearRect` to remove whatever was drawn

```
var poleBar=function(tempVal){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, tempVal);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T2zsM/1/)

Another way to clear the canvas is to reset it's width, like this

```
Canvas.width = Canvas.width;
```

As a sidenote you should always use a radix with parseInt, like this `parseInt(btnnum.value, 10)`

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/T2zsM/2/
before paint canvas is necessary clear it with this line `ctx.clearRect(0,0,20,100);`